# Understanding / controlling the order at which place predictions are returned by the Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I have a sample page that returns airports based on a location searched.   We are doing this because we want to obtain IATA codes for cities in our custom search we are building.

The issue I have is that I don't understand why the results are returned in the order that they are.  The documentation doesn't seem to make reference to this from what I can see.

See my example below where I am doing a search for "London".     Can anyone help clarify this and if there is a way to control it?  Ideally what I want is the airport geographically closest to whatever location I enter.   So in the example of London (where Google like with all cities seems to mark the geocode of a city at it's central geographical point), that would be London City airport.

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
    var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('cityTown'),{types: ['geocode']}
    );

    google.maps.event.addListener(autoComplete, 'place_changed', () => { // arrow function
        this.location.loc = autoComplete.getPlace();
        $.each(this.location.loc.address_components, function(key,value) {
            if(value.types=='country,political'){               
                document.getElementById('country__c').value= value.long_name;
            }
        });
        //console.log('Place changed to: "'+this.location.loc.formatted_address+'"');
    });
}




function getAirports(city){
     
     // Initialize AutocompleteService for airports
     const autoCompleteAirport = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
     // Get input and suggestion list elements
    
     const input = city;
     const suggestionsList = document.getElementById('suggestions');

     // Use AutocompleteService to get airport suggestions based on the city
     autoCompleteAirport.getPlacePredictions({ input: `${input}`, types: ['airport'] }, (predictions, status) => {
         if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
             // Clear previous suggestions
             suggestionsList.innerHTML = '';

             // Display new suggestions
             predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
                    var matches = prediction.description.match(/\((.*?)\)/);

                    //  // Check if there is a match
                    if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
                                const suggestion = document.createElement('li');
                                suggestion.textContent = prediction.description;
                                suggestionsList.appendChild(suggestion);
                    }
                });

                console.log(predictions);
         }
     });
     
}

if(city!=''){ 
    setTimeout(getAirports(city), 5000);
}else{
    alert('No city found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&key=API_KEY"></script>


<script>
// Setup and call function 
var city='London'; 

</script>

<h2>Results from Places API</h2>
<ul id="suggestions"></ul>
```

Comment: Hello! Have you tried using Nearby Search? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Answer (score 0):

The only way to obtain a list of predictions ordered by distance (note: **straight-line** distance) is to have the city's coordinates before calling the API and pass them to the query using `origin: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5287398,-0.1222089)` (in this case i've used coords of the center of London).

Using `origin`, your results will contain the `distance_meters` parameter which represents the straight-line distance from `origin` to the result. Then, ordering results by this parameter, you achieve the expected result (see the example).

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
    var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('cityTown'),{types: ['geocode']}
    );

    google.maps.event.addListener(autoComplete, 'place_changed', () => { // arrow function
        this.location.loc = autoComplete.getPlace();
        $.each(this.location.loc.address_components, function(key,value) {
            if(value.types=='country,political'){               
                document.getElementById('country__c').value= value.long_name;
            }
        });
        //console.log('Place changed to: "'+this.location.loc.formatted_address+'"');
    });
}




function getAirports(city){
     
     // Initialize AutocompleteService for airports
     const autoCompleteAirport = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
     // Get input and suggestion list elements
    
     const input = city;
     const suggestionsList = document.getElementById('suggestions');

     // Use AutocompleteService to get airport suggestions based on the city
     autoCompleteAirport.getPlacePredictions({ input: `${input}`, types: ['airport'], origin: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5287398,-0.1222089) }, (predictions, status) => {
         if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
             // Clear previous suggestions
             suggestionsList.innerHTML = '';

             // Order by straight-line distance
             predictions = predictions.sort(function(a, b) {
                 return a.distance_meters - b.distance_meters;
             });


             // Display new suggestions
             predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
                    var matches = prediction.description.match(/\((.*?)\)/);

                    //  // Check if there is a match
                    if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
                                const suggestion = document.createElement('li');
                                suggestion.textContent = prediction.description;
                                suggestionsList.appendChild(suggestion);
                    }
                });

                console.log(predictions);
         }
     });
     
}

if(city!=''){ 
    setTimeout(getAirports(city), 5000);
}else{
    alert('No city found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&key=AIzaSyBbsCQreb9i_t_d30cSgtf7JLOZlS_aS8U" ></script>


<script>
// Setup and call function 
var city='London'; 

</script>

<h2>Results from Places API</h2>
<ul id="suggestions"></ul>
```